# Using EF to save all changes in the context with a separate function

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

I noticed that in this EntityFramework example each function has its own using statement with the DbContext.

My repository is a bit different where the DbContext is sent in using dependency injection and is set as a private property.

Is it normal to create a function called SaveAll that looks like this:

```
public bool SaveAll()
{
    return _context.SaveChanges() > 0;
}
```

And then have some functions in my repository that never _context.SaveChanges and instead just add items to the context. Then finally just call _repository.SaveAll() to save everything all in one shot.

**On the other hand**

Is it normal to have some functions that have the saving built right into them like this (in the situation where you need to instantly return the new Id of the created object:

```
public Product AddProduct(Product product)
{
    _context.Add(product);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return product;
}
```

It seems like I have a whole variety of functions throughout my project based on the needs and I just want to make sure this is common or see if there is a better way to handle these scenarios.

**Repository functions:**
-That only add to the context
-That add to the context and then save the context

Comment: Any approach can be valid depending on the semantic meaning of what the functionality is doing.  If `AddProduct` is intended to be an atomic operation with side-effects, then it can save the changes itself.  Otherwise consuming code would always be expected to save the changes immediately afterward, which isn't desirable and may not always be done.  On the other hand, if it's meant to be a part of a larger set of operations in a single transaction then calling `SaveChanges()` multiple times throughout such a transaction could be problematic.

Comment: So do you think that doing away with the SaveChanges() function that I created and just always calling SaveChanges() within each individual function is my best bet?

Comment: Not at all.  I'm saying that this is kind of opinion-based and would depend on semantic and architectural concerns not identified in the question.

Comment: It sounds like what David is saying is that you should never "always" do anything, but instead do what is right for the function or use case, whatever that may be, even if it creates a *perceived* inconsistency from the way you do things in other functions/use cases.

Comment: Some very good points mentioned here and I apologize if the question seems opinion based, but TMcKeown told me exactly what I needed to know. When doing web development and handling a web request there should be a single Context instance for the request. And atomic operations should have their own context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no normal...  however if you handling a web request then "normal" would typically indicate a single Context instance for the request, but any operations that need to occur to the DB before that would need their own dedicated DbContext..  The fact that you have some methods that add to the context and immediately save will cause you trouble because you are sharing that context.  Like I stated earlier, IMHO any methods that save all on their own and can be thought of as atomic operations should have their own DbContext created and destroyed within that function.

So changing your atomic operations to this:

```
public Product AddProduct(Product product)
{
  using( var context = new DbContext() )
  {
    context.Add(product);
    context.SaveChanges();
  }

   return product;
}
```

Comment: Alright, so you are saying the one function I showed above where _context.SaveChanges() is actually called within the function itself should be wrapped in using (var db = new MyContext()), otherwise since I am dealing with web everything using the injected context should be using a bunch of functions that only add to the context and then finally call SaveAll(). Make sense? Is there any way to workaround the case where I need to retrieve the productId right away, but still split it into 2 separate functions or do I have no choice but to do what I am doing above?

Comment: Perfect, your update is exactly what I wanted to confirm. So it is okay to have both atomic operations and repository functions that only add to the context when developing web?

Comment: yes, sometimes you need things to "be there" before you send a massive unit of work.